# Any plans regarding Facebook/Twitter/G+?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I see that many other StackExchange sites have Facebook Pages, Twitter, and sometimes Google+ Pages.

Are there any plans regarding this? are these pages managed by site moderators or by volunteers? if so, is there any need for volunteers? (if so, I would like to volunteer).

I think we should begin spreading the word about the site, it's obviously very promising, I think we should give it more work to grow the community.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It's great to see you guys starting to promote your community so early on! We're excited to see you guys have social media pages, but I'd like to ask you to tweak the names and descriptions just a bit. As mentioned in the [trademark guidelines](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) linked in [Kaveh's answer](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/269/96), the names and descriptions of these accounts must make it clear that they are not officially run by SE the company. Changing the name of the profile to something like "Islam Stack Exchange Fans" or "Islam Stack Exchange Community" and including in the description that the account is maintained by you, the community, should suffice.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the only official account associated with the site is the twitter account @StackIslam which is controlled by SE and not the community. Anything else will be an unofficial account set up by some users and not directly related to the site.

[SE has guidelines regarding how trademarks (name, logo) can be used](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance); it is not permitted to use the name and similar other stuff related to the site in a way that implies an official connection without their permission. Content of posts are copyrighted under CC, but the elements of the site itself like the name and logo and similar things are not and cannot be used without permission from SE.

I also don't see a need for an official account on these sites though. Creating more and more pages and accounts is not going to help in make the site successful. If you want to advertise a question on the site you should do it using your own accounts on these sites (e.g. using the share bottons on the questions).

Answer (score 0):

OK, w've created a Facebook Fan Page:

https://www.facebook.com/StackIslam

And a Google+ Fan Page:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/105441808979869850819

And the automatic Twitter bot created by Stack Exchange for every site can be found here:

[@StackIslam](https://twitter.com/#!/StackIslam)

Comment: @StackIslam is an automated bot owned by SE. It tweets upvoted questions. For example, see http://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/1058/revisions, you can see that the post was tweeted.